# Find html code after ajax reponse

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Java Script code**

```
$("#category select").change(function(){
    var category = $('select option:selected').html();

    $.ajax({
        type:"Post",
        url:"collectiepost.php",
        data:"category="+category,
        cache:"false",
        success:function(html){

    $("select").html(html).find("option .category");

        }

        });
    });
});
```

**html output on that page collectiepost.php**

```
<select id="ontwerper">
  <option class="desinger">vikas</option>
</select>
<select id="category">
 <option class="category">cloth1</option>
 <option class="category">cloth2</option>
</select>
```

i want to extract only that part of html

**need output**

```
  <select>
  <option class="category">cloth1</option>
  <option class="category">cloth2</option>
  </select>
```

**problem**

but my code showing all option tag like that

```
  <select>
  <option class="desinger">vikas</option>
  <option class="category">cloth1</option>
  <option class="category">cloth2</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Does the page have one select element or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$("select").html(html).find("option .category");
```

Will set the content of the `select` element to `html`, and then call `find` but do nothing with the result. You need to reduce the HTML fragment returned by your AJAX call before adding it to the DOM:

```
$("select").html($(html).find("option.category"));
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gmHb/). Notice that there is *no space* between `option` and `.category`. Your current selector will match `.category` elements that are *descendants* of `option` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").html(html).find("option:not(.category)").remove();
```

instead of

```
$("select").html(html).find("option .category");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the data, so just do

```
$("select").html($("option.category", html));
```

Which finds the select box, insert the matches of "option.category" from the ajax html.